# Facebook @[userID:User Name] not Mentioning

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm Working on Facebook Application.

normally @[userID:User Name] works.

but since last week, its not working.

Feels like any modification on FB Server, but the Documentations are still same.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#mentions